# "affiliate links" in links to amazon (and others)

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

[This edit](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/4868/revisions) changed a link from

> [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Method-Guitar-DVD-ROM-Berklee/dp/0876390696/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0876390696)

to

> [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Method-Guitar-DVD-ROM-Berklee/dp/0876390696/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0876390696)

What does the "ref" parameter to,
and why should (or shouldn't) we remove it?

I'd like to know so that I can approve (or reject) the proposed edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any referrer parts of the URL will be removed by Stack Exchange automatically, as any Amazon link in a question or answer will get rewritten with a Stack Exchange referral.

So where the Community user has made this kind of edit, it is an automated edit to remove the user referral.

Comment: I doubt it. Surely such an automatic edit would go straight through, not into the suggested edits queue?

Comment: I checked with one of the SE devs - this is what happens.

Comment: Okay. That's a bit weird.